# NIST CPE Name of installed package?

Tags: debian, apt, security

Is there way to get the NIST CPE matching string of a installed package (peferably for debian)?

E.g. Apache HTTP2 is vendor apache and product http_server

I found that out by searching/playing with the CPE matching string and do some searches.

Is there a dictionory or info that maps my installed packaged to it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of one, although I have also looked for it.

If there was one, there would be no need for this 'Debian Enhancement Proposal' to add CPE information to the package meta information.
https://wiki.debian.org/CPEtagPackagesDep

Alas, this change proposal is stale. It has been merged into
https://dep-team.pages.debian.net/deps/dep12/
which was last updated 2014.